# Java - DecimalFormat not rounding off to 2 digits

Tags: java, math, decimal, rounding, decimalformat

I want to round off the numbers to 2 digits only, have written the below code:

```
Double input = 17.755;
DecimalFormat twoDigitDecimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
Double output = Double.valueOf(twoDigitDecimalFormat.format(input));
```

I was expecting output should be `17.76` but it is giving me `17.75` only, for all the other cases it is working perfectly fine, but only this number is not working, if I add one more digit in the input, say `17.7551` then it will roundoff to `17.76`

Comment: [read the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Comment: For your example, `17.751` does not round to `17.76` did you mean `17.7551`? As pointed out in a comment below. `input` is not exactly `17.755` it is the closest value that double can represent. `17.75499...` if you want better accuracy there is [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html). eg `new BigDecimal("17.755");` That way you'll be rounding what you expect.

Comment: Sorry @matt the input was 17.7551 , ive corrected that in the description also

Comment: you can change rounding mode if you need ceiling : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java

Answer (score 1):

First of, your final value is a `Double` **it does not have 2 digits!** When you do Double.valueOf it will become the *closest representable value*. If you actually want two digits in Java then you need to use [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) which actually stores base 10 floating point representations.

The trick is, the value you are using is not what you think it is.

```
double d = 17.755;
```

Java doubles are power of 2 exponent, so a number that appears to be an exact value in decimal, has a repeating representation in float. That means it needs to be truncated and the closest value is used.

```
jshell> double d = 17.755;
d ==> 17.755

jshell> var x = new BigDecimal(d);
x ==> 17.754999999999999005240169935859739780426025390625

jshell> var y = new BigDecimal("17.755");
y ==> 17.755
```

Now you can see that `x` which is an exact representation of `d` is actually less than `17.755` so when you round it it goes **down**.

`y` on the other hand is exactly 17.755 and will round according the the rules you apply.

```
jshell> System.out.printf("%.2f\n", y);
17.76

jshell> System.out.printf("%.2f\n", x);
17.75
```